# Multiple awaits in return statement - problem with overwriting results

Tags: node.js, typescript

## tl;dr

If there are multiple `await` statements in `return` then it seems like last result of `await` overwrites other/previous values of `awaits` in that `return`.

## Problem

In function `funX`, at the end I have following `return` statement:

```
async function funX() {
    return {
        x: await fun1(),
        y: await fun2()
    }
}
```

`fun1` is returning value `1` an `fun2` is returning value `2`.

But `funX` returns:

```
{ x: 2 y: 2 }
```

## Versions

- node version: `v12.18.4`
- npm version: `6.14.6`
- typescript version: `4.0.2`
- os: `Windows 10 Pro, Version 10.0.18363 Build 18363`

Unfortunately I can not provide more code, because its production code.

## What I tried to do

- remove and install node (i tried on latest one and LTS) - problem **still** occurs.
- removed and reinstall all `node_modules - problem **still** occurs.
- writing small code snippet with promises, awaits and return  - but it works **fine**, without any problems.
- consult it with other team members - it looks like Im the only one having this issue.

## Closure

I would be grateful for any hints, ideas or solutions.

Comment: couldn't reproduce it works fine in my fiddle, also tested it with ts locally https://jsfiddle.net/BraveButter/ct0b48a3/7/

Answer (score 0):

Does it make a difference like this?

```
async function funX() {
    const [x, y] = await Promise.all([fun1(), fun2()]);
    console.log(x, y);
  
    return {
        x,
        y
    }
  }
```

Comment: Yes, this works fine, and function `funX` returns `{ x: 1 y: 2 }`. Basically any other combination works fine - like:
```
async function funX() {
const x = await fun1();
const y = await fun2();
    return {
        x,
        y
    }
}
```
also returns `{ x: 1 y: 2 }`

Comment: @Drop please mark as solved.
I think the reason for your version not working is that node can't handle `await` properly in object literals.

Answer (score 0):

Your code definitely works and should work whatever Node.js version you are using if it supports `async`/`await`. You are just missing a comma after `x: await fun1()`.

```js
(async function () {
    const delay = x => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(x), Math.random() * 1000));
    const fun1 = () => delay(1);
    const fun2 = () => delay(2);

    async function funX() {
        return {
            x: await fun1(),
            y: await fun2()
        }
    }

    const res = await funX();
    console.log(res);
})();
```

Comment: Indeed it should. Also it worked fine like few months ago. Recently Ive returned to it and this strange problem occurred. 
PS. Comma - fixed, thx! :)